# I'm having trouble making a button that prints pi

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just starting out in python in my CompSci class, and I was messing around and wanted to create a button to print the value of pi. For some reason, the close window function I made works correctly, but the program automatically prints pi and the print pi button is useless. Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import math
master = Tk()

def closeWindow():
    exit()

button = Button(master, text = "print pi", command = print(math.pi))
button.pack()

button = Button(master, text = "close this window", command = closeWindow)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Keegan, all the solutions below are correct but you might wanna know why this is happening. the command atribute expects a reference to the function you wanna execute when clicked. This is exactly what you're doing with the `closeWindow` function. Notice how we are just writing `closeWindow` instead of `closeWindow()`. With that in mind we now have directly passed the command `print(math.pi)`, this will execute directly. We can even use this principle for making our code more compact instead of `command = closeWindow'`  you can use `command = exit` and remove the `closeWindow` function

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you for the information (: It sounds as if its the parenthesis that make the program process the function directly? @SamuelMiddendorp

Comment: @KeeganSmith Parenthesis are used to 'call' an object. In this case, `closeWindow` is an object that can be called, and so `closeWindow()` is the result of calling `closeWindow`. Passing `closeWindow` instead of `closeWindow()` is the equivalent of handing someone the soft drink fountain instead of a soft drink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the ways above, you can also do this:

```
import tkinter as tk

import math

def command():
    p.set(math.pi)


root = tk.Tk()
p = tk.StringVar()
p.set(' ')
button = tk.Button(root, text='Print pi', command=command)
button.pack()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=p)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `lambda` function to the `command` option of the button.
I have passed lambda function for both the buttons here as the callback function has just a line of code.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import math

master = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(master, text = "print pi", command = lambda: print(math.pi))
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(master, text = "close this window", command = lambda: exit())
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Or You can make it work by creating a separate function and just adding the function as the callback to the button.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import math
master = tk.Tk()

def closeWindow():
    exit()

def print_pi():
    print(math.pi)

button = tk.Button(master, text = "print pi", command = print_pi)
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(master, text = "close this window", command = closeWindow)
button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why did you edit your answer and add a clue from my?

Comment: I never did that. Please don't put such comments.

Comment: Ok, I can see you edited and add the lambda solution at the same time when I was adding mine.

Comment: I never saw your answer until you started commenting on my solution. We might have posted on the same time but I never took a clue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda to call this function only on button click

```
button = Button(master, text = "print pi", command = lambda :print(math.pi))
```